# What did Cal mean by - "Go big or go home"?

Tags: dialogue, plot-explanation, crazy-stupid-love

I have seen [Crazy, Stupid Love](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Ftitle%2Ftt1570728%2F&ei=nWJyUJf2HYvirAf6yYHYCw&usg=AFQjCNFRFd4IvWLY6bhaCn2cRXfS33LoZQ) a while ago. The scene with the big fight among Cal, Jacob, Bernie and David was hilarious. It is one of my favorites.

What I don't understand is what Cal meant when he says to Robbie:

> Go big or go home, right bud

I always thought it meant `Do or die`, but that can't be right.

Is it a famous quote from somewhere else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a common expression to say that if you're gonna try something, try your best or otherwise don't even bother. There are several theories on the Internet to explain the origin but nothing seems to point to specific quotes/song titles/...

Comment: but what was he trying to say to Robbie? It had become too difficult to win Emily back, We saw him saying - `never stop trying` a lot of times; so that's why I guess? what do you think?

Comment: I think he was just refering to the big scene they just had (he 'went big') and yes, probably the advice he was giving him throughout the movie.